# Excel Range Find with a long string 'What' argument

Tags: excel, excel-2016, vba

I use the Range.Find function to look up for a string. 
It seems that this function cannot handle an argument which length is greated than 255, while the max length for a string is way greater than this limit.

I could not find the documentation on this but saw some comments in stackoverflow that would confirm this.

I tried to use a variant instead but it did not work.

Is there a solution to use long What argument with Find ?
Is there an official source to confirm this.
By the way I got the error 13 *incompatible type* while I use the exact same arguments in a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple ways to do that.

When you want to continue using find, you have to search for the first 255 characters and then if a match was found, match the rest. You would search the first substring with a [wildcard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee440632(v=office.12).aspx) at the end, in this case `*`.

The other option is to go through every cell and match it "manually".